# How can I use a cell on new added sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have following codes.

```
 Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q as Range
 Dim z As Integer
 z = Sheet17.Cells(2, 1).Value
  With Sheets.Add
    .Select
    .Name = "PIAF_Summary" & z
    .ScrollArea = "A1:G108"     
  End With


z = z + 1
Columns("B:F").ColumnWidth = 38
With Range("A1:G1")
.Merge
.Interior.ColorIndex = 23
.Value = "Project Name (To be reviewed by WMO)"
.Font.Color = vbWhite
.Font.Bold = True
.Font.Size = 13
 End With

With Range("A5:G5")
.Merge
.Interior.ColorIndex = 23
.Value = "Project Name (Basic Project Information)"
.Font.Color = vbWhite
.Font.Bold = True
.Font.Size = 13
End With
```

**How can I activate added sheet? Since I want add a value to a new sheet cell.**

Comment: What do you mean by activate? Your code already focus new added sheet and allow to add value to cells. So what problem you are facing or what you want?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you declare your variables like this:

```
Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q As Range
```

You have declare only `q as range` and the other ones are declare `as Variant`
So if you want to declare all of them `as Range` you should do it like this:

```
Dim a As Range, b As Range, c As Range, d As Range
```

About your question, you need first to `Set` your sheets in order to work with more easily.

```
 Sub test()

    Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q As Range
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws17 As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws17 = wb.Sheets("Sheet17")

    z = ws17.Cells(2, 1).Value

    Set wsNew = Sheets.Add ' Declare your New Sheet in order to be able to work with after
    wsNew.Name = "PIAF_Summary" & z

    z = z + 1

    wsNew.Columns("B:F").ColumnWidth = 38
    With wsNew.Range("A1:G1")
            .Merge
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 23
            .Value = "Project Name (To be reviewed by WMO)"
            .Font.Color = vbWhite
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 13
     End With

    With wsNew.Range("A5:G5")
            .Merge
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 23
            .Value = "Project Name (Basic Project Information)"
            .Font.Color = vbWhite
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 13
    End With

    'Now you can copy data from Sheet17 to the New created Sheet:
    ws17.Range("A2:C3").Copy wsNew.Range("A2")

    End Sub
```